# Strange result using image augmentation + freezing on keras models

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I started studying deep learning a short time ago and I came across this problem. I used two networks to compare results, ResNetV2 and MobileNet, and in both I froze about 25% of the network and used image augmentation. The problem is that the accuracy graphs have had a high variance and I do not know why.

Is it possible that some image augmentation operation generated very noisy images that made it difficult to generalize? Without freezing the models, using only image augmentation, this variance does not occur, it only occurs when I freeze.

[Graph ResNetV2 accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73xoU.png)

[Graph MobileNet accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aitre.png)

Comment: what is your dataset size, what % of it was used in validation?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. There are 1265 data split into 888 train, 125 val and 252 test. I used ImageDataGenerator from keras in my train dataset with batch size of 32, so 888 // 32  steps per epochs was generate. @ShihabShahriar

Comment: Plz note that your dataset is too small for fine-tuning 75% such complex models. You can turn off image aug., freeze all conv layers or all except last one, and see what happens.

Comment: But my training data generated by the ImageDataGenerator was 44400, but the size of validation data was the same 125. I compared the networks with augmentation and not augmentation, freezing the layers and not freezing, like you suggested, but that variance only occurs with augmentation + freezing 25% layers @ShihabShahriar